# Finding the intersection between sets and awarding points

Tags: python, set, intersection

First, I apologize, I am an extreme beginner, so I will probably sound ignorant.

I have 5 word sets. 4 of them are imported through csv, the other one is created from user input. I would like to find the intersection between the input set and each one of the other sets. Then award points based on how many intersections there are.

For example, I would like to find the intersections between "set_1" and "input_set". For each of the intersections add 1 to user_score. Then, find the intersection between "set_2" and "input_set" and for each of those intersections add 2 to user_score. And so on up to add 4 per intersection.

Would I use an if loop or a for loop?

Something like this?

```
user_score = 0

for x in intersect(input_set, set_1):
    user_score += 1
for x in intersect(input_set, set_2):
    user_score += 2
for x in intersect(input_set, set_3):
    user_score += 3
for x in intersect(input_set, set_4):
    user_score += 4
```

or like this?

```
if intersect(input_set, set_1):
    user_score += 1
elif intersect(input_set, set_2):
    user_score += 2
elif intersect(input_set, set_3):
    user_score += 3
elif intersect(input_set, set_4):
    user_score += 4
```

or am I way off? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ifs aren't loops. Did you attempt to run the code in either block? As @Abernat has pointed out, your code is littered with syntax errors, which suggests not. The first step in solving your code problems is *running your own code*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
for intersect(input_set, set_1):
```

… isn't how for loops work. You need a loop variable, like this:

```
for thing_in_both_sets in intersect(input_set, set_1):
    user_score += 1
```

---

If you don't care what the "thing" is, you can call it `_`. This doesn't have any special meaning, but conventionally it implies that it's a useless dummy variable:

```
for _ in intersect(input_set, set_1):
    user_score += 1
```

---

Meanwhile, if you're using the built-in `set` type, there's no function called `intersect`, but there's a *method* called `intersection`, which you can use like this:

```
for _ in input_set.intersection(set_1):
```

You can also spell this as the `&` operator.

---

However, if you think about it, there's a much quicker way to do this: instead of looping, just get the `len` of the intersection. So:

```
user_score += len(input_set & set_1)
user_score += len(input_set & set_2) * 2
# etc.
```

---

One last refinement: Instead of having four separate variables for the four sets, why not just have a list of sets? Do you also have four copied-and-pasted-with-slight-variations chunks of code to create the separate variables? If so, get rid of them. Then you can do this:

```
user_score = 0
for multiplier, user_set in enumerate(user_sets, 1):
    user_score += len(input_set & user_set) * multiplier
```

Even if you have the separate variables, you can always create `user_set` on the fly, like this:

```
user_sets = (set_1, set_2, set_3, set_4)
```

But it would probably be better to just have a list of the sets in the first place, instead of four separate variables. See [this blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and [this one](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) for more discussion on that.

Comment: @user2825385: Yes, but you don't need those extra parentheses around the `len`, and it might be more readable with `&` instead of `.intersection`—at which point it's basically exactly the same as my middle version.

Comment: Hmm okay, awesome! So, I'm having trouble seeing how the list of sets would be able to differentiate between set_1 and set_2 to be able to award 1 point for set_1 and 2 for set_2 etc..

Comment: That's what I used [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for, so we get the _index_ of each set, along with the set itself. This is one of the most useful functions in Python—it gets rid of so many `for i in range(len(foo))` loops and similar nonsense that you have to write in most other languages.

Comment: ahh! awesome okay, thank you so much! I will use that